# UIAlert View-for yes/no condition

Tags: iphone

my app needs alert msg and with yes button click another alert msg which decides the final action.
I have used **- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex**
this method.

Please help me.

Comment: What kind of help do you need?

Comment: Thaks Marcelo Cantos.I need two alert msg but when 1st one is yes then only 2nd one and if 2nd msg ans is yes then i want to call a method.I have used alert.tag==1 but it is not working.You can see my code.Posted on forum.If you can please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do what @Adrian Pirvulescu said but before showing the alert do `alert.tag = 1;` and then when `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` is called do:

```
if (alertView.tag == 1) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"2nd Alert" 
    message:@"My message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
    otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    alert.tag = 2;
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
else if (alertView.tag == 2) {
    [self CallSomeMethod];
}
else {
    //do what ever you want here
}
```

Comment: Thanks,it is working.But when alert.tag =2 i want to call a method.Where should i call that method because inside the if condition or outside of that i cant called.Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Thank Jamone.But the condition alertView.tag==1 is not working &if i put 0 there then it is working for both buttons.I m posting my code on forum please refer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out
http://www.timeister.com/2010/06/objc-show-alert-iphone/

```
// open a alert with an OK and cancel button
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" 
        message:@"My message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
        otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: Thank Adrian.I have used this,but after ok i want another alert msg and if that is ok then i have to perform my action.
Please help me.

Comment: You just have to listen for *Ok delegate* result and then show a new alert. :)

Comment: Thanks Adrian Pirvulescu,but how to listen for Ok delegate result?
Help me with the code please.
Thanks