# UIAlert View-for yes/no condition

Tags: iphone

my app needs alert msg and if yes button pressed then one more alert msg and then i have to called a method.This is my code:

```
-(IBAction)resetPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *title= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Warning"];
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Are you sure you want to Reset"];
    NSString *ok = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No"];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:ok otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag ==1)
    {
        NSString *title= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Warning"];
        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Are you sure you want to Reset"];
        NSString *ok = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No"];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:ok otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil];
        alert.tag =2;
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }
    else if(alertView.tag ==2)
    {
        [self resetArray];
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank Kenny.In this code alert.tag==1 condition is not gets fulfill so  msg is not getting printed.Also method should get called only when 2 msg is yes.If you can solved this then please.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIAlert View-for yes/no condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165070/uialert-view-for-yes-no-condition) by same user. please alter questions instead of re-posting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your goal is but a few things look wrong to me anyways:

First of all you should create your strings this way:

```
NSString *title= @"Warning";
```

There's no need to use `stringWithFormat` in your case.

Then, it doesn't seem you properly set the first UIAlert's tag to 1, and the default value for tags is 0 so I guess the `if` statements in `didDismissWithButtonIndex` are never true.

Also, you should check which button was pressed using `buttonIndex`, otherwise you are going to show both alert and call `[self resetArray]` whichever button is pressed by the user.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Jukurpa for your suggestion it worked.I checked buttonIndex n problem solved.

Comment: I notice that this great answer isn't accepted, yet.  It's nearly exactly the answer I was thinking in my head when I was reading the question.  Either way, I voted it up.

Pallavi, don't forget to ACCEPT the answer.  This is how you say "thank you" to people on StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you create the first alert, but never actually set the tag on it.  You should do:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:ok otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil];

alert.tag = 1; //Or 2, or something.
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Then the code in your delegate method will run.

Answer (score 0):

Please define two separate UIAlertView in .h file

```
@interface XYZViewController:UIViewController
{
     UIAlertView  *firstAlertView;
     UIAlertView  *secondAlertView;
}
```

Now in your .m file modify as below:

```
-(IBAction)resetPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *title= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Warning"];
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Are you sure you want to Reset"];
    NSString *ok = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No"];

    if(firstAlertView == nil)
    {
       firstAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:ok otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil];
    }
    [firstAlertView show];
```

}

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView == firstAlertView)
    {
        NSString *title= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Warning"];
        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Are you sure you want to Reset"];
        NSString *ok = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No"];

        if(secondAlertView == nil)
        {
            secondAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:ok otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil];
        }
        [secondAlertView show];
    }
    else if(alertView == secondAlertView)
    {
        [self resetArray];
    }
}
```

and in dealloc method please release the allocated UIAlertviews.

Hope i am clear to you.

Thanks,

Jim.

Comment: Thanks Jim.But for both button it is calling resetArray method.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to call resetArray for both alert views?? or you want to call only for secondAlertView??

Comment: Thanks for reply.only for secondAlerView.

Comment: The above implementation will only call ResetArray method on secondAlertView's dismiss event.I also checked with code. ResetArray method is only called for secondAlertView.

Comment: Thanks Jim.Your code works.I just made a minor change,inside the if and else if loop i wrote if(buttonIndex ==1) and its worked.
Thanks.