# UIAlert View to use Button at index 2 ONLY

Tags: ios, uialertview

Ui alert view can pop up multiple times during my one view controller. I want it to do different things. sometimes just want it to do cancel, other i want it to perform actions at button index 2 only (dont offer cancel)

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a very unclear question, try to add more details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165070/uialert-view-for-yes-no-condition

Sorry, i need to tag the ones just for canceling and the ones for actions. i just had to get the question out of my head i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the cancelButton to `nil`. Also in your `UIAlertViewDelegate`, handle click only from buttonIndex = 2.